# zip -r with ~/ partially replicated my system directory

Tags: macos, zip, nw.js

I am trying to zip my nw.js application into a zip file. So I run this:

```
"win.sh" 3L, 121C
cp ~/nout/package.nw ~/nout/win/QuantumPilotWin/package.nw
zip -r ~/nout/QuantumPilotWin.zip ~/nout/win/QuantumPilotWin
```

I expected the zip file to be of a single folder, that of `QuantumPilotWin`

instead I get this structure[image]:

How do I `zip` without the full path?

EDIT:

Trying Joe's steps I got this in the unzipped folder:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run the zip -r command when you are in ~/nout/win/, so:

```
cd ~/nout/win/
zip -r ~/nout/QuantumPilotWin.zip QuantumPilotWin
```

Comment: That's better.. but still gave me a Users subdirectory. see edit

Comment: @quantumpotato what's the contents of that Users folder?

Comment: I put it in an edit (2nd screenshot from the bottom)

Comment: That's because the command above *added* to your original zip file. You need to delete the zip file first, and re-run command above.

Comment: @HuguesM., I tried that with cp ~/nout/package.nw ~/nout/win/QuantumPilotWin/package.nw
rm ./QuantumPilotWin.zip
zip -r ~/nout/QuantumPilotWin.zip ~/nout/win/QuantumPilotWin

Comment: @quantumpotato are you still having issues?

Comment: @Joe yeah, made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795258/zip-r-replicates-users-directory to avoid extended discussion in comments. Include full script